# How to load modal dialog with layout content?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

How and where should I define region or function with modal dialog functionality so that I can load it in one or two specified cases in views e.g. like through `MyApp.modal.show(content)`?

Example:

```
var ModalRegion = Backbone.Marionette.Region.extend({
  el: "#modal",

  constructor: function(){
    _.bindAll(this);
    Backbone.Marionette.Region.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    this.on("view:show", this.showModal, this);
  },

  getEl: function(selector){
    var $el = $(selector);
    $el.on("hidden", this.close);
    return $el;
  },

  showModal: function(view){
    view.on("close", this.hideModal, this);
    this.$el.modal('show');
  },

  hideModal: function(){
    this.$el.modal('hide');
  }
});
```

How to use it in this view?

```
MyApp.Views.Layouts.Unauthenticated = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: 'layouts/unauthenticated',

  regions: {
    //modal: ModalRegion, //Region must be specified as a selector string or an object with selector property
    tabContent: '#tab-content'
  },
  events: {
    'click #showLogin': 'showLogin'
  },
  views: {},
  showLogin: function(){
    this.views.login = BD.Views.Unauthenticated.Login;
    MyApp.modal.show(new this.views.login);
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do with two another ways.

1) Using opensource for tw bootstrap [this](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone.bootstrap-modal) and [without bootstrap](https://github.com/GarethElms/BackboneJSModalView)

2) If you prefer own modal, I recommed to do your own "base" class to define your abstract methods. Example in coffeescript:

```
class MyApp.Views.Base.Modal extends Marionette.ItemView
  ... here is modal code like show etc.... just abstract class

class MyApp.views.model_custom extends MyApp.Views.Base.Modal
  ... and here is class with specific details of one modal like element, events, triggers etc...
```

in javascript:

```
var MyApp.Views.Base.Modal = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({...}) 
var MyApp.views.model_custom = MyApp.Views.Base.Modal.extend({...})
```

and its strongly recommended do this with all classes like itemView compositeView, make base classes...